# How to configure, develop and running jaggery project using developer studio using eclipse for WSO2

Tags: javascript, wso2, mashup, jaggery-js

I couldn't find the proper tutorial for, 
How to configure, develop  and running jaggery  project using developer studio using eclipse for WSO2.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the reference to the official Jaggery Artifact documentation in WSO2 Dev Studio from [here](https://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS350/Creating+Jaggery+Artifacts).

Hope this helps!

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana

Comment: Hi Harshana Martin Thanks for your reply. Could you please tell me how to run the jaggery application in eclipse also how to configure the server to run it in eclipse?

Comment: I believe article in http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/05/jaggery-debugger/ will help you to runa dn debug Jaggery application in Eclipse. At the moment it is not possible to deploy a Jaggery application to an Carbon Server using a CAR file. We are working on fixing it for the next Carbon release.

Comment: Hello Harshana, is it possible to deploy a Jaggery Web App to a Carbon Server now?

Comment: Hi @flock.dux Developer Studio 3.7.0 and later versions are capable of producing the CAR file with Jaggery Apps. However the UES 1.0.0 or AS 5.2.1 is still unable to deploy them via CAR files. I have created 2 Jiras for them. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-15201 and https://wso2.org/jira/browse/UES-568 Once these are fixed, complete solution will be there.